# Nodejs handling 2 file uploads - not multiple files, but two distinctive image fields

Tags: node.js, file

I am working on a nodejs project and I want to try and upload two different images from two different fields.

[image]

can I do something like this?

```
  app.post("/api/flowers", upload.single('image_day'), upload.single('image_night'), flowerController.createFlowerData);
```

how would I capture the 2 image fields -- as before when I had 1 file and it was handled like this - but req.file.

```
  let imageBuffer = req.file?.buffer;
  const expectedSizeOfFile = req.file?.size;
```

is there a way of handling this by let imageDayBuffer = req.file?[image_day].buffer  and  let imageNightBuffer = req.file?[image_night].buffer

---

I managed to get this working using fields

```
  app.put("/api/garden/:garden_id", upload.fields([{ name: 'image_day', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'image_night', maxCount: 1 }]), gardenController.editGarden);  



 let imageDayBuffer = req.files?.image_day[0]?.buffer;
 const expectedSizeOfFileDay = req.files?.image_day[0]?.size;
```